# Add a table to a Linq data context

Tags: linq

I have created a new table in my database and want to add it to the data context. If I drag it to the designer surface I get a message telling me the object I am adding uses a different data connection and asking if I want to replace the connection in the designer.  I answer no.

I then add a new class to the data context and configure it the same as one in another project where I had dragged the table into the designer surface, and which works, meaning it reads from the database.

The class I added and configured does not attach to the underlying database table and thus does not read from the database.

I suspect a problem I had with the other project resulted from dragging this table to the designer surface and replacing the connection.

Can a new class be attached to or made to use a database table, and if so how?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that you right click on the newly added class and and select "Configure Behavior" then choose a behavior. Evidently I just defined the connection but not how to implement it.

I would, however, warn against any type of modification of an existing dbml file. I have done this many times by adding classes and by dragging and dropping tables to the designer surface. In all cases the database connections have become in-operabel.

Comment: I don't know that this caution is warranted, as I do this all the time without issue.  It sounds like you had two different connections to the database that you were dragging from.